# Error When Loading Data from HDFS and Writing to HBase using Pig

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-pig, hdfs

How to load the output data of a mapreduce program which is in the hdfs into hbase?

I tried to running the following pig command to load the data from hdfs to hbase:-

```
A = LOAD 'hdfs://b**/user/user1/development/hbase/output/part-00000' USING PigStorage('t') as (strdata1:chararray, strdata2:chararray); 
STORE A INTO 'hbase://mydata' USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage('mycf:strdata2');
```

where, `hdfs://b**/user/user1/development/hbase/output/part-00000` is the map-reduce output `mydata` is the hbase table name created 
`mycf` is the column family name

I am getting the following error:-

```
ERROR 2017: Internal error creating job configuration.

org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobCreationException: ERROR 2017: Internal error creating job configuration. 
  at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler.getJob(JobControlCompiler.java:673) 
  at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler.compile(JobControlCompiler.java:256) 
  at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher.launchPig(MapReduceLauncher.java:147) 
  at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine.execute(HExecutionEngine.java:378) 
  at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeCompiledLogicalPlan(PigServer.java:1198) 
  at org.apache.pig.PigServer.execute(PigServer.java:1190) 
  at org.apache.pig.PigServer.access$100(PigServer.java:128) 
  at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.execute(PigServer.java:1517) 
  at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeBatchEx(PigServer.java:362) 
  at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeBatch(PigServer.java:329) 
  at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.executeBatch(GruntParser.java:112) 
  at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:169) 
  at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:141) 
  at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.exec(Grunt.java:90) 
  at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:406) 
  at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:107)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: hbase://mydata_logs at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.initialize(Path.java:148) 
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:71) 
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:45) 
  at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler.getJob(JobControlCompiler.java:476) 
  ... 15 more
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: hbase://mydata_logs at java.net.URI.checkPath(URI.java:1787) 
  at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:735)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.initialize(Path.java:145)
```

Comment: Does this help you - http://blog.whitepages.com/2011/10/27/hbase-storage-and-pig/ - Have you set the env variables as per the getting started section of this article?

Answer (score 1):

Only remove the hbase:// schema from data source string like that :
STORE A INTO 'mydata' USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage('mycf:strdata2');